# Multiple instances of Visual Studio Code on multiple Windows virtual desktops

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, virtual-desktop

On Windows 10 I frequently use it's virtual desktops feature. I usually need multiple instances of VS Code to be opened in different virtual desktops. The little inconvenience I'm having is to do with opening a file with VS Code on one virtual desktop, while last used VS Code instance is on another virtual desktop. The file gets opened on that last used instance and Windows switches to that virtual desktop.

I have found VS Code configuration options that seem to be related:

- `"window.openFilesInNewWindow":"<default|on|off>",`
- `"window.openFoldersInNewWindow":"<default|on|off>",`
- `"window.openWithoutArgumentsInNewWindow":"<on|off>",`

But all they let us configure is either opening files in last used instance or in new instance no matter what. As I understand, as of now VS Code is not aware of virtual desktops.

My question is: Would it possible to set up VS Code (or maybe Windows itself) in such way, that it opens files with VS Code instance that is running on virtual desktop that is in focus at that moment?